# How to send cookies from nodejs to angularjs in REST-API response

Tags: node.js, angular, express, session, cookies

I am using nodejs with angularjs for front-end, I am using REST-APIs for getting resources from node server. I want to use cookies to maintain sessions.

I am using 'cookie-parser':

```
var express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

and I am sending cookies using:
But the cookies are not getting set in the browser.

```
res.cookie('Authentication', token, { maxAge: 60*60*12, httpOnly: true});
```

If anybody has some different approach also please mention.

Comment: are you using specific IP or localhost to run your server?

Comment: running in localhost currently

Comment: and can you share frontend code, which interacts with the server.

Comment: login(username, password) {
    return this.hc.get('http://localhost:3000/api/login?email=' + username + '+&password=' + password + '&key="secret");
  } through a form

Comment: hc is HttpClient Object

Comment: you need to set `withCredentials:true` in your headers at client side.

Comment: Thanks its working but getting other error in the console while sending data: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/login?email=tr@com+&password=12345&key=secret' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194406/discussion-between-therightdoctors-and-mehta-rohan).

Comment: Hello @mehta-rohan, but When I use withCredentials:true with the post request I get an error: Chrome error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/api/url' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. and in the node server I get: OPTIONS req url